# "Error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version" PHP Issues with Time Comparison

Tags: php, mysql

Every time I try to format a php MySQLi Query, I keep getting a formatting error that tells me to check the manual - although Im not sure what exactly is wrong with it.

```
$timeCheckEmp1 = "SELECT * FROM employee1 
   WHERE employee1.starttime BETWEEN $appointmentDateTime AND $endDateTime 
     OR $appointmentDateTime BETWEEN employee1.starttime AND employee1.endtime"    

$getResultEmp1 = mysqli_query($link, $timeCheckEmp1) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

For the record, I have tried converting the queued dates as both strings and dateTime values, and I still get the error.

The only help the PHP server is giving me is that it is occuring around the `"AND ($endDateTime value) OR  (appointmentDateTime value) BETWEEN employee1.starttime AND employee1.endtime"`.

Any advice is advice is appreciated.

Comment: $appointmentDateTime etc need to be quoted

Comment: Strings need to be quoted in SQL. You'll be better off using parameterized queries any way. Additionally 1. You don't need the table name preceding the columns if there is only 1 table. 2. You shou describe the issue in the title of your question, not copy/pasting the error.

Comment: I'm fact so does all your variables in SQL. And your code is not injection safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think $appointmentDateTime and $endDateTime should be quoted.

```
$timeCheckEmp1 = "SELECT * FROM employee1 WHERE employee1.starttime BETWEEN '$appointmentDateTime' AND '$endDateTime' OR '$appointmentDateTime' BETWEEN employee1.starttime AND employee1.endtime";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM employee1 
WHERE (employee1.starttime BETWEEN $appointmentDateTime AND $endDateTime )
OR ($appointmentDateTime BETWEEN employee1.starttime AND employee1.endtime)
```

Comment: @Ratata did you try this?